# How to call description in python API

Tags: python, api

I want to call the description on weather api using python but it gives me this error when i put the code, but i search everywhere and i cant see it.

heres the code

```
des = response['weather']['description']
print("Description = ",des)
```

but im getting this error

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Please post an example of the API response you are trying to parse.

Comment: try response[weather][0] or response[0][description]

Comment: "Weather":[{inside here the info, }] the solution is in the bottom. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using this will fix it:**

```py
des = response['weather'][0]['description'][0]
print("Description = ",des)
```

Hope this helps!

**NOTE:**

Next time add your JSON code to the post to make stuff easier.

Comment: Im trying to get the description of the weather im so sorry for the late response its already morning here and im re searching it. But yours is the besti did. Thank you for the response.. you save me.